# Reactstrap layout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm new to reactstrap and I have some issues with the layout.

I would like to design a connection container like following example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th8Bj.png)

When I resize my screen for smaller screens, the text is layered over the image. And it's not aligned properly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFQM.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB4tb.png)

The code I have for this layout is:

```
render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="page-content">
                    <Container fluid>
                                <Card>
                                    <CardBody>
                                        <AvForm className="form-horizontal" onValidSubmit={(e, v) => {
                                            this.handleValidSubmit(e, v)
                                        }}>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col sm="3"><img src={mollieImage} style={{
                                                    width: '300px',
                                                    height: "auto",
                                                    boxShadow: "3px 3px 2px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.62)"
                                                }}/></Col>
                                                <Col sm="9">
                                                    <Row><h5>Connection Status</h5></Row>
                                                    <Row><p>Allow access to your customers, payments, organization, profiles and onboarding.</p></Row>
                                                    <Row>
                                                        {this.props.isConnected ? <Button type="submit" color="danger">Disconnect</Button> :
                                                            <Button type="submit" color="success">Connect</Button>}
                                                    </Row>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </AvForm>
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your image to be responsive, I'd refactor the `300px` value to be `maxWidth` instead of `width`. As for its `width` you can have it be responsive to its container by assigning `100%` to it.

```
<Col sm="3"><img src={mollieImage} style={{
  maxWidth: "300px",
  height: "auto",
  boxShadow: "3px 3px 2px rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.62)",
  width: "100%"
}} /></Col>
```

With regards to the smaller screens view, the prop `sm` on your `Col` components will only kick in if the screen size is greater than or equal to `576px`. See the sample `col-sm-` definition on the Bootstrap stylesheet

```
@media (min-width: 576px)
.col-sm-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

So when the client's screen size if less than `576px`, that is when the `sm` prop will start to lose effect thus your layout changes drastically. For that, your going to have to come up with solutions such as using `xs` prop or CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)